# Importing 3d models opengl

Tags: opengl, 3d, models

I wanna write my own importor and it would be pretty much the first i would write. I wanna import a 3d file that also has animations in it.The Question is which would be easier ? I wanna import smt that programms like 3ds Max and blender can export to but im not really sure which would be eaier ( i don't care if it takes a long time but i just want it to be understandable)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily find a number of sources for code fragments to get you start on either format.  For instance, here's a pretty small fragment of C++ code to get you start on 3DS loading into an OpenGL format:

http://www.codersource.net/MFC/OpenGL/Loading3DfilesfromOpenGLOpenGLTutorial7.aspx

Most of your work will be decoding the file formats into the appropriate C++ and OpenGL constructs.  Blender has a nice aggregator on file formats:

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Resources/File_Formats

I haven't worked with both of these formats, so can't offer an opinion on which is easier.